# How to get the data from database into different textboxes on selecting a name in the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page with different textboxes on entering the values in the textboxes and clicking "save" button it is saving into the database.I will post an image in order to understand what am i asking.
[image]

So the question is when i enter a name such as "Ferrari" the textbox of "Organisation Name" should scroll down giving the names starting like "Ferrari Constructions","Ferrari Resources","Ferrari Motors","Ferrari Racing".Now i will select a name like "Ferrari Motors" then it should fetch the data of "Ferrari Motors" and display the data into all other textboxes automatically in the sense like autofiling.
NOTE:No need to fill the tabular data automatically.Only Textboxes should be filled.I am posting the code below

Ihome.jsp

```
<script language="javascript">
                    // Add row to the HTML table
                       function generate(){
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                        var f1 = document.form;
                        f1.setAttribute("target","_blank");
                        f1.method="post";
                        f1.action='Invoicedisplay.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
                        f1.submit();
                    }


                    function generate1(){
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                        var f = document.form;
                        f.target="";
                        f.method="post";
                        f.action='addInvoice.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
//                         f.submit();
                    }


                      function generatePdf(){
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                        var f = document.form;
                        f.method="post";
                        f.action='invoiceDisplayPdf.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
                        f.submit();
                    }

                     function generateWord(){
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                        var f = document.form;
                        f.method="post";
                        f.action='invoice_display_word.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
                        f.submit();
                    }
                </script>


<!--                 <center> -->
                    <form name="form" action="Invoicedisplay.jsp" method="post">
<!--                      <center>  <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="header"/> <b>Include Letter Head?</b></center>  -->
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8">
                                        <tr>

                                            <td width="134"><div align="center"><strong><u> BILLED TO</u></strong></div></td>
                                            <td width="160">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="8">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="8">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="140">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="149"><strong><u>TAX INVOICE</u> </strong></td>
                                            <br/>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>OrganisationName</strong></td>
                                            <td><input name="bname" type="text" id="bname" value="" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td ><strong>Invoice NO. </strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="invNo" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>
                                            Delivery Address</strong></td>
                                            <td><textarea name="bDelivAdd" cols="21" rows="3" id="bDelivAdd"></textarea></td>

                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                            <td ><strong>InvoiceDate </strong></td>

                                  <td>
                              <input type="text" id="invoiceDate" name="invoiceDate" class="search_textbx" readonly="readonly" placeholder="&nbsp &nbsp dd-mm-yyyy"/> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>PhoneNo.</strong></td>
                                            <td><input name="bno" type="text" id="bno" value="" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td><strong>Buyer Order No. </strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="buyerOrderNo" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>PAN No.</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="bpan" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td><strong>Buyer Order Date </strong></td>

                                  <td>
                              <input type="text" id="buyerorderDate" name="buyerorderDate" class="search_textbx" readonly="readonly" placeholder="&nbsp &nbsp dd-mm-yyyy"/>  </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>Attention</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="bAttn" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                             <td><strong>Mode/Terms of Payment </strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="termsOfPmnt" /></td>

                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>Esugam No</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="esugamNo" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td><strong>Delivery Note </strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="delivNote" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>Dispatch Document No</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="dispDocNo" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td ><strong>Dispatch Through</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="dispThrough" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>Dispatch Date </strong></td>

                                  <td>
                              <input type="text" id="dispatchDate" name="dispatchDate" class="search_textbx" readonly="readonly" placeholder="&nbsp &nbsp dd-mm-yyyy"/></td>


                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td><strong>Destination </strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="destination" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>Terms of Delivery</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="termDelivery" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td><strong>Discount </strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="discount" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-left:50px;"><strong>Buyer VAT/TIN</strong></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="bTinNo" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                             <td style="padding-right:10;"> <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="cstCheck"/><b>Buyers CST No</b></td>

                                            <td><input type="text" name="bcstNo" /></td>
                                             </tr>
<!--                                             <tr> -->
<!--                                            <td style="padding-right:10;"> <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="cstCheck"/><b>Buyers CST No</b></td> -->
<!-- <!--                                             <td><strong>Buyers CST No  </strong></td> --> 
<!--                                             <td><input type="text" name="cstNo" /></td> -->
<!--                                         </tr> -->
                                    </table></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br/>

                         <center>
                         <div style="width:900px; height:230px; overflow:auto;">




                      <table id="my_table" align="center" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <thead><tr>
                                        <th>Select</th>
                                        <th>Sl.no</th>
                                        <th>Description of Services/Goods</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Price/Unit</th>  
                                        <th>CST %</th>                                      
                                        <th>VAT5.5</th>
                                        <th>VAT14.5</th>
                                        <th>ServiceTax</th>


                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>


                         </div>
                         <br>
                         </center>
                          <center>
                        <hr/>
                        <bgcolor ="red"/>
                        <input type="button" value="Add row"  name="add" onClick="addRow()"  />
                        <input type="button" value="Delete selected rows" name="delete_all" onClick="deleteSelectedRows()" />
                        <input type="button" value="Delete all rows" name="delete" onClick="deleteAllRows()" /><br/>
                        <hr/>
                        <p>
                            <strong>
                                <label for="servtax"></label>
                            </strong> 
                            <input type="submit" value=" Save" onclick="generate1()" />
                            <input type="submit" value="View Invoice" onclick="generate()" />
<!--                             <input type="submit" value="View Invoice in Pdf" onclick="generatePdf()" /> -->
                             </center>
                             <hr/>
                    </form>
```

addinvoice.jsp

```
<body>
    <%
        String organizationName, phoneNo, buyDate, invoiceNo, buyerOrderNo, esugamNo, deliveryAddress, PANNo, deliveryNote, invoiceDate, termsofPayment, dispatchDocumentNo, attention, dated, dispatchThrough, destination, termsOfDelivery, discount, buyerTin, buyerCSTNo;
            int CId =0;
            organizationName = request.getParameter("bname");
            phoneNo = request.getParameter("bno");
            buyDate = request.getParameter("buyerorderDate");
            invoiceNo = request.getParameter("invNo");
            buyerOrderNo = request.getParameter("buyerOrderNo");
            esugamNo = request.getParameter("esugamNo");
            PANNo = request.getParameter("bpan");
            deliveryNote = request.getParameter("delivNote");
            invoiceDate = request.getParameter("invoiceDate");
            attention = request.getParameter("bAttn");
            dated = request.getParameter("dispatchDate");
            dispatchThrough = request.getParameter("dispThrough");
            destination = request.getParameter("destination");
            termsOfDelivery = request.getParameter("termDelivery");
            discount = request.getParameter("discount");
            buyerTin = request.getParameter("bTinNo");
            buyerCSTNo = request.getParameter("bcstNo");
            deliveryAddress = request.getParameter("bDelivAdd");
            termsofPayment = request.getParameter("termsOfPmnt");
            dispatchDocumentNo = request.getParameter("dispDocNo");

            try{
        DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
        Connection con = db.getCon();
        String sql ="insert into marketing_database.invoiceclient_details (OrganizationName,PhoneNo,BuyDate,InvoiceNo,BuyerOrderNo,EsugamNo,DeliveryAddress,PANNO,DeliveryNote,InvoiceDate,TermsOfPayment,DispatchDocumentNo,DispatchThrough,Destination,TermsofDelivery,Attention,Discount,BuyerTin,BuyerCSTNo,Dated) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
        PreparedStatement  ps =con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, organizationName);
        ps.setString(2, phoneNo);
        ps.setString(3, buyDate);
        ps.setString(4, invoiceNo);
        ps.setString(5, buyerOrderNo);
        ps.setString(6, esugamNo);
        ps.setString(7, deliveryAddress);
        ps.setString(8, PANNo);
        ps.setString(9, deliveryNote);
        ps.setString(10, invoiceDate);
        ps.setString(11, termsofPayment);
        ps.setString(12, dispatchDocumentNo);
        ps.setString(13, dispatchThrough);
        ps.setString(14,destination );
        ps.setString(15, termsOfDelivery);
        ps.setString(16, attention);
        ps.setString(17, discount);
        ps.setString(18, buyerTin);
        ps.setString(19, buyerCSTNo);
        ps.setString(20, dated);

        ps.executeUpdate();

        //Get Max CID
        String sql1 ="Select MAX(CId) from marketing_database.invoiceclient_details";
        PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        ResultSet rs  =ps1.executeQuery(sql1);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            CId =rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("CId====="+CId);
        }
        con.close();
        ps.close();
        ps1.close();
        rs.close();
        System.out.println("Saved to Invoice Details");
            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            //
            String createdBy=(String)session.getAttribute("email");

            String row = request.getParameter("rowCount");   
            System.out.println("Row Count====="+row);
            int rowCount = Integer.parseInt(row);


            String item,description;
            String CST;
            int quantity;
            double perUnitPrice;

              String serviceTax =null, vat5 = null, vat14 = null;

              try{
          DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
          Connection con = db.getCon();
                String sql = " select vat5,vat14,serviceTax FROM marketing_database.tax_info WHERE id='1' ;";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                vat5 = rs.getString("vat5");
                vat14 = rs.getString("vat14");
                serviceTax = rs.getString("serviceTax");
               // CST = rs.getString("CST");
            }
            con.close();
            ps.close();
            rs.close();
              }
              catch(SQLException ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
              }
         int j=1;


         List<Double> cstAmountList= new ArrayList<Double>();
         List<Double> vat5AmountList= new ArrayList<Double>();
         List<Double> vat14AmountList= new ArrayList<Double>();
         List<Double> svcTaxAmountList= new ArrayList<Double>();

         while (j < rowCount) {

        float serviceTaxDB = 0, vat5DB = 0, vat14DB = 0;

        description = request.getParameter("discription" + j);


         if(request.getParameter("quantity" + j)==null ||request.getParameter("quantity" + j).equals(""))
            {
                quantity=0;
            }
            else{
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity" + j));
            }

            if(request.getParameter("price"+ j)==null ||request.getParameter("price"+ j).equals(""))
            {
                perUnitPrice=0;
            }
            else{
                perUnitPrice = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"+ j));
            }



//      quantity = Integer.parseInt(request
//              .getParameter("quantity" + j));

//      perUnitPrice = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"+ j));

        double totalPrice = (quantity*perUnitPrice);

        CST =request.getParameter("CST"+ j);
        float cst;
        if(CST==null ||CST=="")
        {
             cst=0;
        }
        else{
             cst=Float.parseFloat(CST);
        }

              double cstAmnt=0,vat5Amnt=0,vat14Amnt=0,serviceTaxAmnt=0;


               cstAmnt = (totalPrice*cst)/100;
               //rounding to two decimal places
               DecimalFormat cstroundoff = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
               String cstround = cstroundoff.format(cstAmnt);
               double cstroundofff = Double.parseDouble(cstround);
               cstAmountList.add(cstroundofff);


               String[] tax;
                  int length;
                  tax = request.getParameterValues("tax" + j);
                  if(tax==null ||tax.equals(""))
                  {
                      length=0;
                  }
                  else{
                      length = tax.length;
                  }

//                String[] tax;

//                tax = request.getParameterValues("tax" + j);
//                int length = tax.length;
                  System.out.println("length===="+length);
                  if (tax != null) {
                      for (int k = 0; k < tax.length; k++) {
                          if (tax[k].contains("vat5")) {

                             vat5DB = Float.parseFloat(vat5);
                              vat5Amnt = (totalPrice*vat5DB)/100;
                               // rounding to two decimal places

                              DecimalFormat vat5roundoff = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                              String vat5round = vat5roundoff.format(vat5Amnt);
                              double vat5roundofff = Double.parseDouble(vat5round);
                              vat5AmountList.add(vat5roundofff);
                          }
                          if (tax[k].contains("vat14")) {

                            vat14DB =Float.parseFloat(vat14) ;
                            vat14Amnt = (totalPrice*vat14DB)/100;
                            //rounding to two decimal places
                            DecimalFormat vat14roundoff = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                            String vat14round = vat14roundoff.format(vat14Amnt);
                            double vat14roundofff = Double.parseDouble(vat14round);
                            vat14AmountList.add(vat14roundofff);
                          }
                          if (tax[k].contains("serviceTax")) {

                             serviceTaxDB = Float.parseFloat(serviceTax);
                              serviceTaxAmnt = (totalPrice*serviceTaxDB)/100;
                              //rounding to two decimal places
                              DecimalFormat svcroundoff = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                              String svcround = svcroundoff.format(serviceTaxAmnt);
                              double svcroundofff = Double.parseDouble(svcround);
                              svcTaxAmountList.add(svcroundofff);
                          }

//                        if (tax[k].contains("cst")) {

//                           CSTDB =Float.parseFloat(CST);

//                        }
                      }
                  } 
                  try{
                      DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
                      Connection con = db.getCon();
                      String sql ="INSERT INTO marketing_database.invoice (CId,CreatedBy,DescriptionOfGoods,Quantity,PerUnitPrice,VAT5,VAT14,ServiceTax,CST,TotalPrice) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
                      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                      ps.setInt(1, CId);
                      ps.setString(2, createdBy);
                      ps.setString(3, description);
                      ps.setInt(4, quantity);
                      ps.setDouble(5, perUnitPrice);
                      ps.setDouble(6, vat5Amnt);
                      ps.setDouble(7, vat14Amnt);
                      ps.setDouble(8, serviceTaxAmnt);
                      ps.setDouble(9, cstAmnt);
                      ps.setDouble(10, totalPrice);
                      ps.executeUpdate();
                      System.out.println(" Saved to invoicing !!");
                     con.close();
                     ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            j = j + 1;

        }
           double subTotal =0.0;
           double cstTotal =0.0;
           double vat5Total= 0.0;
           double vat14Total = 0.0;
           double svcTaxTotal =0.0;
         try{
             DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
              Connection con = db.getCon();
                    String sql = "select SUM(TotalPrice) FROM marketing_database.invoice WHERE CId='"+CId+"' ;";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        subTotal=rs.getDouble(1);

                    }
                    int cstSize = cstAmountList.size();
                   System.out.println("CST size==="+cstSize);
                    for(int i=0;i<cstSize;i++)
                    {
                        cstTotal+=cstAmountList.get(i);
                    }
                    int vat5Size =vat5AmountList.size();
                    System.out.println("vat5 size==="+vat5Size);
                    for(int i=0;i<vat5Size;i++)
                    {
                        vat5Total+=vat5AmountList.get(i);
                    }
                    int vat14size = vat14AmountList.size();
                    System.out.println("vat14 size==="+vat14size);
                    for(int i=0;i<vat14size;i++)
                    {
                        vat14Total+=vat14AmountList.get(i);
                    }
                    int svcSize = svcTaxAmountList.size();
                    for(int i=0;i<svcSize;i++)
                    {
                        svcTaxTotal+=svcTaxAmountList.get(i);
                    }

                    Double grandTotal =subTotal+cstTotal+vat5Total+vat14Total+svcTaxTotal;
                    int roundofff = (int) Math.round(grandTotal);
                    String sql1 = "UPDATE `marketing_database`.`invoiceclient_details` SET `SubTotal`=? ,`grandTotal`=? , `cstAmount`=? ,`vat5Amount`=? ,`vat14Amount`=?,`svcTaxAmount`=? WHERE `CId`='"+CId+"';" ;
                    PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
                    psmt.setDouble(1, subTotal);
                    psmt.setDouble(2, roundofff);
                    psmt.setDouble(3, cstTotal);
                    psmt.setDouble(4, vat5Total);
                    psmt.setDouble(5, vat14Total);
                    psmt.setDouble(6, svcTaxTotal);
                    psmt.executeUpdate();
                    con.close();
                    psmt.close();
                    System.out.println("Sub total updated in Invoice details");
         }
         catch(SQLException ex)
         {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         }
        response.sendRedirect("Ihome.jsp");
    %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `jQuery` for exchanging the data from the server on each event,

check the data for and bind it with your repective elements,

```
$.ajax({
     type:'post',      //you can use any method here
     url:'serverpth',
     data:{b: 'ok'},   //your data which you are looking for from database
}).success: function(data){
    // bind your fields here with data
};
```